# apache camel multithreading within route

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-camel

I have these routes:

```
    @Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    String overviewRoute = this.routingProperties.getReportingRoute(OverviewtRouteConstants.OVERVIEW);

    this.from(overviewRoute).routeId(overviewRoute).threads(1, 100).choice()
            .when(this.simple(BODY_GRAPH_NAME + GraphConstants.OVERVIEW_OPEN_LANE + "'"))
            .to(this.routingProperties.getReportingRoute(OVERVIEW_OPENLANES_TO))
            .when(this.simple(BODY_GRAPH_NAME + GraphConstants.OVERVIEW_BELT_DOWNTIME + "'"))
            .to(this.routingProperties.getReportingRoute(OVERVIEW_BELTDOWNTIME_TO))
            .when(this.simple(BODY_GRAPH_NAME + GraphConstants.OVERVIEW_LUGGAGE_THROUGHPUT + "'"))
            .to(this.routingProperties.getReportingRoute(OVERVIEW_LUGGAGETHROUGHPUT_TO))
            .when(this.simple(BODY_GRAPH_NAME + GraphConstants.OVERVIEW_LANE_UTILIZATION + "'"))
            .to(this.routingProperties.getReportingRoute(OVERVIEW_LUGGAGETHROUGHPUT_TO))
            .when(this.simple(BODY_GRAPH_NAME + GraphConstants.OVERVIEW_LUGGAGE_SCANNED + "'"))
            .to(this.routingProperties.getReportingRoute(OVERVIEW_LUGGAGESCANNED_TO));
}
```

Rest service endpoint:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
@Service(SERVICE_NAME)
public class OverviewServicesImpl extends BaseServices implements OverviewServices {

@Override
public Response overview(OverviewSearchDTO dto) {
    return this.executeRouting(OverviewtRouteConstants.OVERVIEW, dto);
}

}
```

Context :
The main route *overviewRoute* is called from a ws REST endpoint. The others routes are called according to when clause.

My front end calls the main route multiple times in parallel.

What I see:
All routes defined in "choice" clause are called sequentially (The next route is called once the previous one has finished).

What I want:
I want that the route defined in choice clause must be called as soon as a ws called is done and not once the previous call is done.

What I have tried:
Apache seda
Spring Scope:  @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like all the `.when` clauses are returning True, so it is following all choices. I am not sure the part within your `.when` clauses is an actual comparison? Am I missing how you are doing the compare to check parts of the message to compare and route in the Context Based Router?